# Does settings API create settings on run time?

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm tweaking a plugin and I'd like to have an option value different for each backoffice user.

Currently the options are defined using the `add_settings_field` method that is performed in the `admin_init` hookup.

My question is, could I register a new set of settings by prefixing my settings using the current user ID?

Such a way, if valid, could help to solve other problems, such:

- [How to Set an Individual Homepage for Each User?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63914/how-to-set-an-individual-homepage-for-each-user)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98060/settings-api-creating-setting-fields-on-the-fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can and it's easier using a Class. In the `admin_init` hook (where the Settings API is being registered and defined) set a class property based on the user ID:

```
$this->prefix = 'uid_' . get_current_user_id() . '_';
```

Then, in the rest of the code, refer to your option name as `$this->prefix . 'option_name'`.

The result in the table `wp_options` will be `uid_1_option_name`, `uid_2_option_name`, etc. And each user will have its own settings.

<sup>A [Gist](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/6603046) with a working example.</sup>